# Flutter desktop save pdf in user selected location

Tags: flutter-desktop

I need to save a invoice as pdf. The PdfServide is as below:

```
class PdfService {
  static Future<File> saveDocument({
    required String name,
    required Document pdf,
  }) async {
    final bytes = await pdf.save();
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${dir.path}/$name');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

    return file;
  }

  static Future openFile(File file) async {
    final url = file.path;

    await OpenFile.open(url);
  }
}
```

which saves the file in 'C:\Users\username\Documents'

But I want to save the pdf file in user selected location. How can I make that happen?

After using file_selector and file_selector_windows package:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getSavePath on channel plugins.flutter.io/file_selector)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`file_selector` plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/file_selector) provides a `getSavePath` function to prompt the user for a save location.

The desktop implementations aren't yet endorsed, so for now you'll also need to add a dependency on [`file_selector_windows`](https://pub.dev/packages/file_selector_windows), [`file_selector_macos`](https://pub.dev/packages/file_selector_macos), and/or [`file_selector_linux`](https://pub.dev/packages/file_selector_linux) to enable the plugin for desktop platforms.

Comment: Hi, I imported both packages and got the error.\

Comment: Do you see a reference to `file_selector_windows` in `windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc`? If not, you're not actually using it, which would give you that error.